# clang compiler hangs on windows

Tags: c++, windows, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

I have built **clang** with VS9 following [manual](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows).

It was built without errors. But when I am trying to compile some code - it hangs (not consuming cycles, two processes), both trunk and 3.2 release:

```
> "bin\clang++.exe" -c test.cpp -o test.bs -emit-llvm -v

clang version 3.2 (tags/RELEASE_32/final)
Target: i686-pc-win32
Thread model: posix
 "C:/llvm/bin/clang++.exe" -cc1 -triple i686-pc-win32 -emit-llvm-bc -disable-free -main-file-name test.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -target-cpu pentium4 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -coverage-file "C:\\llvm\\test.bs" -resource-dir "C:/llvm/bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.2" -fmodule-cache-path "C:\\Users\\qble\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\clang-module-cache" -internal-isystem C:/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.2/include -internal-isystem -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fmsc-version=1300 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o test.bs -x c++ test.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.2 based upon LLVM 3.2svn default target i686-pc-win32 -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -mstackrealign -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fmsc-version=1300 -fdelayed-template-parsing -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -o test.bs -x c++ test.cpp "
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/llvm/bin/../lib/clang/3.2/include
End of search list.
[HANG IS HERE]^C
```

What is wrong? How to make it work?

EDIT:

> Can you find where the second process is launched? Is its stdin redirected to a pipe?

Second proccess is executed here, it is "clang.exe":

```
>clang.exe!llvm::sys::Program::ExecuteAndWait(const llvm::sys::Path & path={...}, const char * * args=0x001ba3f0, const char * * envp=0x00000000, const llvm::sys::Path * * redirects=0x00000000, unsigned int secondsToWait=0, unsigned int memoryLimit=0, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > * ErrMsg="")  line 34  C++
clang.exe!clang::driver::Compilation::ExecuteCommand(const clang::driver::Command & C={...}, const clang::driver::Command * & FailingCommand=0x00000000)  line 282 + 0x24 bytes C++
clang.exe!clang::driver::Compilation::ExecuteJob(const clang::driver::Job & J={...}, const clang::driver::Command * & FailingCommand=0x00000000)  line 298 + 0x10 bytes C++
clang.exe!clang::driver::Compilation::ExecuteJob(const clang::driver::Job & J={...}, const clang::driver::Command * & FailingCommand=0x00000000)  line 303 + 0x12 bytes C++
clang.exe!clang::driver::Driver::ExecuteCompilation(const clang::driver::Compilation & C={...}, const clang::driver::Command * & FailingCommand=0x00000000)  line 508 + 0x15 bytes  C++
clang.exe!main(int argc_=3, const char * * argv_=0x001b28c0)  line 476 + 0x1e bytes C++
```

EDIT:

If I run:

```
type test.cpp | ..\build\bin\Debug\clang.exe -emit-llvm -c test.cpp -o test.bs
```

Or command line from above clang output directly - I am getting real compile error (about header). So, it looks like some problem with arguments parsing/passing.

Comment: Since you built `clang`, you can rebuild it with debug symbols.  And then capture a stack trace.

Comment: I did this - it waits second proccess, but I haven't checked what second process is doing.

Comment: @BenVoigt hm, second process waits input from <stdin>

Comment: Can you find where the second process is launched?  Is its `stdin` redirected to a pipe?

Comment: So `args` is empty, or `args[0]` is `"clang.exe"` ?

Comment: That's good, since past bug reports on `llvm::sys::Program::ExecuteAndWait` indicated there could be problems if `args[0]` wasn't set right.

Comment: oops, I made wrong tests, arguments are actually ok (3.2). I just looked to VS debug popup which showed only one argv[0]...

Comment: lauching process from console directly - works. need to check what is wrong with arguments...

Comment: How about just `echo | clang.exe `...?  Perhaps it's reaching end-of-file on stdin that helps, and not actually having source code supplied.

Comment: no, that doesn't help - it waits real source code from stdin

Comment: @BenVoigt problem localized, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with my **INCLUDE** env var. It had path like

```
c:\some\dir\
```

clang passed it to subprocess (Win **CreateProcess** accepts concatenated args):

```
clang.exe someargs "c:\some\dir\" otherargs
```

and looks like due to last backslash, double quote was "escaped", because argv_ in subprocess was:

```
somepath/clang.exe
someargs
c:\some\dir" otherargs
```

note how backslash was "used", and that **otherargs** concatenated with that path, that why it waited  - it didn't get part of args.

Clang's **Program::Execute** should be fixed to support escaping of backslash or code which parses **INCLUDE** env var.

**EDIT** from [Stefan v.K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2230775/stefan-v-k): Corresponding entry in llvm bug tracker with a possible patch. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15802

Comment: good catch, meanwhile I guess you can workaround it by not having a trailing backslash.  Or use POSIX-style directory separators `/`.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what did (both: removed trailing, and converted others to `/`)

Comment: @artlessnoise thank you! so, as bug is reported, I am accepting answer.